# Merge and Sort log files - multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash

I have multiple log files in a directory and I need to merge and sort them according to date.
I would like to do it in bash/shell because i need to do it in an existing script.
Some messages are printed on multiple lines
Each message start with date (2021-06-29 10:31:26)

```
2021-06-29 10:31:26 message Log1  example -line 1^M
Second line of message

2021-06-29 10:31:25.437839 PID29559 message Log2 example
```

Comment: Maybe look at awk and give it a record separator. How are the log records delimited? Are lines that start with a timestamp a new log record?

Comment: @teambob Yes if a line start with date (2021-06-29 for example) it is a new message, and message can have new lines

Comment: I have updated my solutio and added a comment too

Comment: @davidbobo : _in bash/shell, because i need to do it in an existing script._ : I don't understand this argument, because you can invoke any program from your existing script, no matter what  language is is written it. I hope that you don't insist that your solution would completely run in the **same process** as your existing script, i.e. without spawning any child processes???

Answer (score 1):

Try this this works

```
cat 1 2 3 >merge;grep -E -i -w "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" merge|sort
```

explanation

this is the contents of file 3 having multiple lines

```
2022-02-10
2022-02-11 dhqwiodhiqowdhqwdh
```

this is the contents of 1 2 3 file ( by cat)

```
cat 1 2 3 

2020-12-24
2021-02-23    djiowdhiwod
2022-02-10
2022-02-11 dhqwiodhiqowdhqwdh
```

output after running the entire command (`cat 1 2 3 >merge|grep -E -i -w "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" merge|sort`)

```
2020-12-24
2021-02-23    djiowdhiwod
2022-02-10
2022-02-11 dhqwiodhiqowdhqwdh
```

**cat** : will display all the contents and then merge.

**grep**: will pick out all the lines with date

**sort**: will sort the messages accordingly

Comment: Did you mean cat 1 2 3 >merge && grep -E -i -w "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" merge|sort
It print only the line that start with a date, it doens't print the second line

Comment: No, try my command, in the as it form, it prints everything, offcourse this command will print lines starting with date, if you want second or third line too then you wont be able to sort them, because for sorting you need a criteria like here i am sorting based on date, but there second and third line will start from characters then sorting and desired results in not possible

Comment: 1. This is my question - some message are on multiple line - so this doesn't help me
2. cat 1 2 3 >merge will redirect output to file and then pipe don't get any ouptut
3. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: let me try finding somethinng for multiple line but pipe thing is working in my system

Comment: @JatinMehrotra : If you add the `-h` option to grep, you don't need a temporary file, but can simply do a `grep -h .... 1  2 3`.

Comment: Thank you for the input you can edit if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Try rust-based tool [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 /var/log
```

*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher* handles multi-line log messages.

> I would like to do it in bash/shell because i need to do it in an existing script.

`s4` can run from a shell; it's a typical CLI program. But if you meant "pure bash" then this answer may not help.